# SQL convert column headers to row values

Tags: sql, csv

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| Group# |  Person A |  Person B  |  Person C |
+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|      1 |   yes     |   no       |   no      |
|      2 |   no      |   yes      |   yes     |
|      3 |   yes     |   yes      |   yes     |
```

I want to use a SQL query on this data that will return the Group# in one column and the column header in the second column when the value = yes. The result I want would look like this for the above table:

```
+-----------+----------+
| Group#    |  Person  |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | Person A |
|         2 | Person B |
|         2 | Person C |
|         3 | Person A |
|         3 | Person B |
|         3 | Person C |
+-----------+----------+
```

*Note that in contrast to my example, my actual data has many more columns than rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best approach is a lateral join.  But the most general method is simply `union all`:

```
select group#, 'personA' as person
from t
where personA = 'yes'
union all
select group#, 'personB' as person
from t
where personB = 'yes'
union all
select group#, 'personC' as person
from t
where personC = 'yes';
```

In answer to your next question . . . yes, you have to explicitly list the columns.  However, you can use a SQL query on the metadata tables to generate the query you really want.  And then execute that query.